# code igniter - how to pass an array which is stored in a virable from controller to model

Tags: codeigniter, variables, model, controller

this is my controller which i made a form in my view and i get the data from user and store it in an array $insertdata

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Add_book extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('desktop/header');
        $this->load->view('desktop/add_view');
        $this->load->view('desktop/footer');
    }
    public function add_new(){
        $insertdata = array(
            'logo'=>$this->input->post('logo'),
            'sazman'=>$this->input->post('sazman'),
            'title'=>$this->input->post('title'),
            'time'=>$this->input->post('time'),
            'category'=>$this->input->post('category'),
            'test'=>$this->input->post('test'),
            'tashrih'=>$this->input->post('tashrih')
            );
    }
}
```

and this is my model which i want  to pass my $insertdata to it and make some query with it like inserting it to data base at first step and then update and so on

```
    <?php
class Add_book_model extends CI_Model{
function __construct(){
parent::__construct();
}
 function add_book_model($insertdata){

    if ($this->db->insert('add_book', $insertdata) === FALSE) {
    die('Error Insert unsuccessful');
  } else {
    $this->load->view('desktop/succes');
  } 
}

 }
?>
```

now my question is how can i send $insertdata from my controller to my model as i want my model to process and make the query when i copy the if statement to my controller is works fine but when i place that in my model it just show a blank page and this is my view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter!</h1>


    <div id="body">
        <h1>here u add ur quiz book</h1>
        <?php
        $this->load->helper('form');
        echo form_open('add_book/add_new');
        $data = array(
              'name'        => 'logo',
              'class' =>'custom'
            );
         echo "<p>something</p>";
         echo form_input($data);
         $data2 = array(
              'name'        => 'sazman',
              'class' =>'custom2'
            );
         echo "<p>something</p>";
         echo form_input($data2);
         $data3 = array(
              'name'        => 'title',
              'class' =>'custom3'
            );
          echo "<p>something</p>";
         echo form_input($data3);
         $data4 = array(
              'name'        => 'category',
              'class' =>'custom4'
            );
          echo "<p>something</p>";
         echo form_input($data4);
         $data5 = array(
              'name'        => 'time',
              'class' =>'custom5'
            );
          echo "<p>something</p>";
         echo form_input($data5);
         $data6 = array(
              'name'        => 'test',
              'class' =>'custom6'
            );
          echo "<p>something</p>";
         echo form_input($data6);
         $data7 = array(
              'name'        => 'tashrih',
              'class' =>'custom7'
            );
          echo "<p>something</p>";
         echo form_input($data7);
         echo form_submit('submit','submit');
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
$this->load->model("Add_book_model");

$this->add_book_model->add_book_model($insertdata);
```

**In model, change `add_book_model()` function name, since the class and function name is same, the function in mdel will be considered as constructor.**

In model

```
function insert_books($insertdata){

if ($this->db->insert('add_book', $insertdata) === FALSE) {
      die('Error Insert unsuccessful');
   } else {
      $this->load->view('desktop/succes');
   } 
}
```

In controller

```
$this->add_book_model->insert_books($insertdata);
```

Comment: thnkx the problem was the name of fucntion as u mentioned i didnt know that and i am thankfull of you

Comment: Glad i could help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

**In Controller**

```
$this->load->model("Add_book_model"); # load model
$result = $this->Add_book_model->add_book_model($insertdata); # passing data to model method

if($result == true){
    echo " Success";
}
else{
    echo "Fail";
}
```

**Syntax**

```
$this->model_name->function_name(value);
```

---

**In model**

```
function add_book_model($insertdata){ # Catching input parameter which comes from Controller 

    if(!$this->db->insert('add_book', $insertdata)){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: your syntax helped it was the name of my function in model problem which was the same of filename

Comment: @user3357687 happy to help